# Wikidata SPARQL filter field values by language

Tags: sparql, wikidata

So I have this SparQL query that gets the information of the United States dollar

```
SELECT 
?currency ?page_title ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217 
(GROUP_CONCAT(distinct ?shortName; separator = ', ') as ?shortNames)  
    {  
        ?currency wdt:P498 ?currencyIso4217 .  
        OPTIONAL {?currency wdt:P1813 ?shortName} .    
        ?article schema:about ?currency ; schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>; schema:name ?page_title    
            SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'nl' }  
            {
                BIND(wd:Q4917 AS ?currency).  
                OPTIONAL { 
                     SERVICE wikibase:label 
                             { 
                               ?shortName rdfs:label ?shortNameLabel . 
                               bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'nl'  
                             }  
                         } 
             } 
      }  
group by ?currency ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217 ?page_title
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcurrency%20%3Fpage_title%20%3FcurrencyLabel%20%3FcurrencyIso4217%20%0A%20%20%20%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28distinct%20%3FshortName%3B%20separator%20%3D%20%27%2C%20%27%29%20as%20%3FshortNames%29%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcurrency%20wdt%3AP498%20%3FcurrencyIso4217%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fcurrency%20wdt%3AP1813%20%3FshortName%7D%20.%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcurrency%20%3B%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%3B%20schema%3Aname%20%3Fpage_title%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%27nl%27%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28wd%3AQ4917%20AS%20%3Fcurrency%29.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FshortName%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FshortNameLabel%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%27nl%27%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20%3Fcurrency%20%3FcurrencyLabel%20%3FcurrencyIso4217%20%3Fpage_title)

This outputs:
[image]

Now when I look at the WikiData page of the USD, and then to the "short names" section I see this:

[image: Wikidata image]

They all have a language property between brackets. Now my question: what I want in my query is to have only the "English" version of the short name in it and filter out all the other languages. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is strangely convoluted and I believe you have been led down that path due to a long-standing bug with GROUP_CONCAT in such situations (at least I seem to remember something like that–can't quite look it up right now).

Anyway, here is something that I believe works for you purposes, at least in theory. Practically, there just aren't enough "short names" for it to matter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?currency ?page_title ?currencyLabel ?currencyIso4217 ?shortName WHERE 
  {  
    ?currency wdt:P498 ?currencyIso4217 .  
    ?article schema:about ?currency ; schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>; schema:name ?page_title .          
    
    OPTIONAL {
      ?currency wdt:P1813 ?shortName .
      FILTER(LANG(?shortName) = "en") .
    }    
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'en' }  
  }
```

[Link to query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcurrency%20%3Fpage_title%20%3FcurrencyLabel%20%3FcurrencyIso4217%20%3FshortName%20WHERE%20%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcurrency%20wdt%3AP498%20%3FcurrencyIso4217%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fcurrency%20%3B%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%3B%20schema%3Aname%20%3Fpage_title%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcurrency%20wdt%3AP1813%20%3FshortName%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3FshortName%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%27en%27%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%20%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3FshortName%29)

You'll notice that I cut out a whole of stuff. But I think the one idea that you've been grasping for is just the line with *FILTER*. And maybe that LANG(?string) gets you the language.

Comment: THanks! Now I see your query getting all currencies I see that it is not worth to even get the short name as all other currencies do not even have the property.
Thanks a lot. It does the job!